# selecting same column twice for different value

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have a table like this;

```
event_id  pair  versus  score
       1     1      11    100
       1     1      12      0
 ...
       1    11       1      0
       1    12       1     50
```

Now I want to get the both scores for a given pair on the same result row.
Like;

```
event_id pair versus score1 score2
       1    1     11    100      0
       1    1     12      0     50
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you always have pair , the following should give you desired result:

```
SELECT a.event_id ,a.pair,a.versus,
a.score as score1, b.score as score2
FROM table_name a
INNER JOIN table_name b on
(a.event_id = b.event_id and b.pair =a.versus and b.versus=a.pair and a.pair<b.pair)
```

Side notes.
1. It makes sense to have a surrogate primary key column in the table.
2. The query would look much cleared if you had one more column which serves as pair identifier  (ie. both 1-11 and 11-1 would share the same pair_identifier).
3. `a.pair<b.pair` added to avoid duplicates in resultset